# Cloudflare URL forwarding specific urls

Tags: cloudflare

Very basic question I have about CloudFlare page rules.

I want the URL "ghbrewsupply.com/register" to forward to "gilehousebrewsupply.com/register.php".

I have both the domains on CloudFlare and as of now.

I would really love to hear what anybody has to say about this, never knew you could create page rules like this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick. Under Cloudflare page rules:

if URL matches

```
*ghbrewsupply.com/register
```

Pick a setting > Forwarding URL  (302 Temporary Redirect)

```
https://gilehousebrewsupply.com/register.php
```

Good luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded soon, this is what I saw on Cloudlfare's blog and it did work. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Thanks @DilionSmith, I'm pleased this worked for you.